# Disjoint unions with undefined tag

Tags: flowtype

The JSON data model I work with is a nested structure made up of branch nodes and special nodes which are disambiguated based on the existence of a `$type` key, e.g.:

```
{ "a": { "b": { "$type": "special" } } }
```

I'd like to model this using Flow, but tagged unions seem to require that the distinct tags are of the same type, e.g.:

```
// @flow
type Special = { $type: 'special'};
type Branch = { $type: ?null, [key:string]: any };

function isSpecial(param: Special | Branch): ?Special {
    if (param.$type === 'special') {
        return param;
    }
}
```

Gives the following error:

```
$ node_modules/.bin/flow check-contents < example.js 
-:2
2: type Special = { $type: 'special'};
                            ^^^^^^^^^ string literal `special`. This type is incompatible with
3: type NotSpecial = { $type: ?null, [key:string]: any };
                                ^^^^ null

-:3
3: type NotSpecial = { $type: ?null, [key:string]: any };
                                ^^^^ null. This type is incompatible with
2: type Special = { $type: 'special'};
                            ^^^^^^^^^ string literal `special`

-:3
3: type NotSpecial = { $type: ?null, [key:string]: any };
                                ^^^^ undefined. This type is incompatible with
2: type Special = { $type: 'special'};
                            ^^^^^^^^^ string literal `special`


Found 3 errors
```

Is there a way to handle a case such as this?

Answer (score 0):

While in theory this should work, this is not supported by Flow. Flow requires tags to have the same type.